# Ext js forms, models and file uploads

Tags: extjs4

I would like to clarify how do ext 4 models correlate to form panels.
Suppose I have a model, e.g. "User", which has a REST proxy attached.

When I want to modify user parameters, i use form's

```
loadRecord( Ext.data.Model record ) : Ext.form.Basic
```

method, to set form's field values.

After modification, I call "updateRecord" method, to send changes from form to loaded model, and then use model's "save" method, to send changes to server. This works quite well, and seems to fit Ext MVC concepts.

## Question

But, the question is: how should I conform to MVC, in case I need to upload file, while modifying user's data (e.g. avatar). According to what I learned from docs, I should switch to using form's "submit" method to send updated data so server, including the file.

In this case, I see several drawbacks:

- The original model, loaded to the form, will not be updated.
- If I update the model (using "updateRecord", or other way), the model will stay in dirty state, however, changes have already been sent to server.
- The same proxy configuration should be applied to form, as to model, so that I would not need to change server side.

Is this a correct way of implementing file-upload through ext forms?
Is there any way to do this using model.save method, to be more MVC-stylish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can combine two thing together. File upload will always be something different than submitting the rest of the data. What you can do however:

- Have a button to select and upload file to the server. But don't save file into the same place where you save your user (for example you can have separate file storage and save just file name into the user record)
- When sending user record update to the server send new file name. This way your avatar update and other data update will be in the same transaction.

Comment: Most browsers do not reveal selected file name/path, I do not think this is possible.

Comment: You don't need to reveal file/path - you need to submit a file first to your server. Server will save it and return some name (which is name of this file on your server), you will use this name later when updating user record.

Comment: this is overcomplicated: Send file, receive file, reply fileId, accept fileId and only then call model.save(). 4 new actions to support just one.

Comment: Then don't do this. And have separate actions for avatar and regular fields.